# Unable to connect to docker on VS code

Tags: python, docker, containers, openai-api

I was trying to build a chatbot for company use, and I was following this tutorial from Microsoft.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/get-started-app-chat-template?tabs=visual-studio-code#architectural-overview

I just simply follow all the steps using VS code, after signing in to Azure and clone the repository, I got an error saying

```
An error occurred setting up the container.
```

I have the Docker Desktop installed and opened, and tested it with

```
docker run hello-world
```

It can successfully create image and container for the hello-world demo. However, I didn't see any image nor container created regarding to the chatbot.

I am not familiar with Docker/container, can anyone assist me? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you make an image for your chatbot?

Comment: @MUFF. How am I supposed to do that? I don't see in the tutorial that I need to make an image?

Comment: I would suggest reading the [docker documentation for creating an image](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/base-images/) and also checking out [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/14pe3ea/azure_services_migration_to_docker/).